# friendly_id and rspec controller tests, finding the correct id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, friendly-id

I have a simple rspec controller test for basic crud functions. I've recently added Friendly_id to my controller - now all the tests are failing.

```
describe "PATCH update" do

      context "where the record is found" do 
        before do
          allow(model).to receive(:find).and_return(instance)
        end

        context "where the record is a root" do 
          before do 
            allow(instance).to receive(:root?).and_return(true)
          end

          context "where the record is updated" do
            before do
              allow(instance).to receive(:save).and_return(true)
              patch :update, instance.slug
            end

            it "should set a flash notice" do 
              flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
            end

            it "should redirect to panel page" do 
              response.should redirect_to(admin_corporate_pages_path)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

all of which fail with the following error,

```
 1) Admin::CorporatePagesController for authenticated users GET edit returns http success
     Failure/Error: get :edit, id: corporate_page
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `friendly' for #<Class:0x007f993a956b88>


  2) Admin::CorporatePagesController for authenticated users PATCH update where the record is found where the record is a root where the record is updated should set a flash notice
     Failure/Error: patch :update, instance.slug
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/corporate_pages"}
```

this is the relevant controller,

```
  def update
    if @corp_page
      @path = (@corp_page.root? ? admin_corporate_pages_path : admin_corporate_page_path(@corp_page.root))
      if @corp_page.update_attributes(params[:corporate_page]) 
        flash[:notice] = 'Page updated'
        redirect_to @path and return 
      else
        flash[:error]= 'There was an error'
        render :new and return
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "Record not found"
    end
    redirect_to admin_corporate_pages_path
  end

  private
    def get_corp_page
      @corp_page = CorporatePage.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I don't see how it could make a difference seeing as friendly id uses the :id function anyway. How could it have made such a difference to the tests?

Comment: How is instance defined in your test? Is friendly_id grouped in your Gemfile?

Comment: @BroiSatse its available to all envrionments. i set instance by 

  let(:instance){FactoryGirl.create :corporate_page}

Comment: Does your factory include a slug column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix. Firstly your instance does not have a slug attribute set, which results in the error no 2. Also your call seems incorrect, it should be:

```
patch :update, id: instance.to_param      # Let model decide which column it is to use
```

Second error is caused by:

```
allow(model).to receive(:find).and_return(instance)
```

Change it to:

```
allow(model).to receive_message_chain(:friendly, :find).and_return(instance)
```